# Good names for turning site responsive-ness on and off?

Tags: terminology, responsive-design, names, many-options

I'm doing work on a website that has been 1900px wide long time, and most of the users aren't extremely tech-savvy and usually +40 years old. To give you an idea of the content of the website, all the pages contain graphs and tables with lots of data.

I've decided to wing this with a little 'lean' in mind and do a few pages at a time, testing the waters and see how the users like my options for tables and graphs on mobile devices in an environment that doesn't require pinch zooming

For the sake of not bothering the users too much if they prefer the old 1900px wide site even on mobiles and tablets, I've put an option in the footer to turn the media queries on and off, which is where I'm now struggeling a little.

currently it reads:

Let content adapt to screen size: *Full original size (desktop)*. *Adaptive size.*

The two options are colored blue, italic, and the currently selected one is underlined. Visually I think it works fine, but I would like some help with what I could name the two options

1) Full original size (desktop)

2) Adaptive size

I'm sort of new at this, so please ask questions if I'm unclear on something.

Comment: Mobile mode on/off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about "Fixed width (original size)" and "Match my screen width"?

Since your audience is 40+ and not really tech-savvy, they probably aren't going to know what "Adaptive size" is.

Comment: Or just "Adjust to screen size". Or "Adjust to my screen size". Or "Fit in screen".

Comment: I really like the "(original size)" as the users will probably seek normality if they are uncomfortable. Though i prefer @Paul s "Adjust to screen size" as it holds some formality which might seem more professional. Thanks for the input!

Comment: I also think it'd add to usability if you made the currently-selected option non-linked (and make it obvious that it's not a link).